# MySQL Multiple Databases for User Authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication, multiple-databases, dbd

I have a few related web sites and it seems rather unfortunate that they have completely separate user databases. I've been contemplating different options on how to unify the databases:

1. Rework the sites to be running on one copy of my content management system rather than independent software. Pros: Seems clean. Cons: Complicated by needing to rewrite a lot of the backend of one of the sites to support the different features of the other site.
2. Use the OAuth backend I wrote to interface with Facebook to authenticate back and forth between the sites. Pros: Seems to be using OAuth for what it was meant to do. Cons: it requires at least some redundancy where I'd need to store duplicate user data on both sites and this could get out of sync. Also seems like overkill for two sites running on the same server.
3. Connect to both databases whenever an account is created or modified on either site and apply the modifications to the other site. Pros: seems to avoid risk of falling out of sync and avoids complications of having to create and receive OAuth data between the sites. Cons: it requires full duplication of user information between the sites.
4. Choose one of the sites as having the canonical database and have the user authentication mechanism of the other site connect to the first site's MySQL database, while still connecting to a separate database for the rest of the site's functionality.

I'm not totally happy with any of the options, although #4 feels like the simplest to implement as I'm thinking about it. Nonetheless, before I embark on such a project, I thought I'd ask for potential pitfalls I might be overlooking since none of the ideas are entirely trival. I'd appreciate advice on which might be considered "best practices" and, perhaps, more importantly, which one would cause the most impact on server resources. I'm using Perl's `DBD::MySQL` to interact with the databases.

Comment: Personally I'd lean towards #2, as it offloads authentication onto the auth provider (so enabling you to focus your attentions on your application); and is IMHO the most easily extensible for the future.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal. Assuming I'm doing the auth authentication though, which would you pick? That is, I don't necessarily want to make people use Facebook or Twitter to sign in... I'd want people to be able to still sign directly in to the sites if they prefer. (Which presumably means I'm going to need to create an OAuth server to go with my OAuth client...)